# get URL for a page receiving the re direction

Tags: javascript, url-routing

When clicking the red button 
[image]
on [this page](https://my.service.nsw.gov.au/MyServiceNSW/index#/rms/trans/renewRegistration/login), it takes me to "another" page with a different url, which when I copy and paste in a different tab, expecting to see the same "last/new" page, I see the previous/old page with the red button.

How can I get the url for the new page which loaded after clicking the button? So that I can use it in my javascript code. Thanks

Comment: if you inspect the button element you will see that there is no url, there only function which handle it your button `transAuth.guestLogin()`, so you can put it manually in your code `https://my.service.nsw.gov.au/MyServiceNSW/index#/rms/trans/renewRegistration/selectRegistration`

Comment: It sounds like you didn't build this. It is written in angular. I wouldn't start changing things unless you know what you're doing

Comment: this is an angular project..the button isn't directly linking to a separate page but does some internal routing first

Comment: @Smile0ff The link you suggested loads a different page than the page loaded when the red button is clicked. That is not the page I want but the page loaded when the red button is clicked.:)

Comment: Step 1: `https://my.service.nsw.gov.au/MyServiceNSW/index#/rms/trans/renewRegistration/selectRegistration` + `https://my.service.nsw.gov.au/MyServiceNSW/index#/rms/trans/renewRegistration/selectRegistration` = `https://my.service.nsw.gov.au/MyServiceNSW/index#/rms/trans/renewRegistration/login`